# How to apply color alternatively for table group rows?

Tags: angular, css, typescript, angular-material2

I want to display the table row as an alternative color for group of rows. I have used below code for alternate color but the requirements is different. If there is group of rows are same color remains should be the alternative color. Am using Angular 7, material Design 2 platform.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color : white;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color : gray;
}
```

**The expected behavior should be as below Screenshot.**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with _"If there is group of rows are same color remains should be the alternative color. "_? Do you want even/odd colors or something else?

Comment: @DanielB Yes i want Even/odd color but as above example, if 3rows are gray color then the next row should be white. likewise need to display alternative color.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. How do you group your rows? In your example it's "1 gray / 1 white / 3 gray / 1 white / 2 gray / 1 white / 2 gray / 1 white" and I can't see a connection here...

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic or stats like 1,3,4,5,7,8,10,11? Or can it be 2,4,5,6,8,9,11,12 aswell?

Comment: @Swoox Its Dynamic.. Example: Odd is red & Even is blue, 
1 - will be Red color,
2 - will be blue color,
   3 & 4 are same group then
3 - will be Red color,
4 - will be Red color,
5 & 6 & 7 are same group then
5 - will be blue color,
6 - will be blue color,
7 - will be blue color ,
8 - will be red color,
Likewise Alternative colors based on group of row.

Comment: So this is set in the component? So you can make like `this.month[i].color = true` where color = true will be gray.

Comment: @Swoox table tr will generate by *ngFor. if any group we should check and pass the any Flag

Comment: I'm confused now I'm talking about the component(.ts) not the html(view).
How does your data(JSON) for the ngFor looks like?

Answer (score 0):

there you can easily get this by simple code in Angular 7.
By using ngClass we can achieve this i.e.

```
[ngClass]="index == 0?'active':'dull-white'"
```

You can use your condition there and achieve your thing.
Comment your queries if any.

Comment: no, if i follow this the output will be the different. the active rows are "gray" color and rest of the rows will be "dull-white" color. I should display exactly the sample image.

Comment: any pattern you use or just this?

Comment: Just this alone.

Comment: then change the class of every tr accordingly it will make your work done as
`<tr style="background-color:grey">Jan</tr>
<tr style="background-color:white">Jan</tr>
.
.
.
.
`

Comment: No, 
Example: Odd is red & Even is blue, 1 - will be Red color, 2 - will be blue color, 3 & 4 are same group then 3 - will be Red color, 4 - will be Red color, 5 & 6 & 7 are same group then 5 - will be blue color, 6 - will be blue color, 7 - will be blue color , 8 - will be red color, Likewise Alternative colors based on group of row

Comment: It is not the exact solution I am giving you an example now you can do it the same as above.